# Keydown event not firing in Android Firefox?

Tags: android, jquery, firefox

I was testing some pages on Firefox for Android (just updated Firefox and using Nexus 4) and noticed that my keydown functions weren't firing. I made a simple example below and found that the keydown doesn't fire when I start typing letters into the input, but does when I hit space, backspace, enter, numbers, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input').on('keydown', function() { alert('keydown'); });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keydown(function() {
  alert('Handler for .keydown() called.');
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. In fact going to http://api.jquery.com/keydown/ and trying the example with Android Firefox doesn't seem to work...